# OSB fn:bea Function using XQuery Engine in Java

Tags: java, xquery, saxon, bea

After some research I haven't found a solution, but quite alot of people with this problem:

I am trying to do a XQuery Transformation in a Java Application using

```
net.sf.saxon.s9api
```

However I get this error when trying to compile        `XQueryExecutable exec = compiler.compile(...));` my XQuery:

```
    Error on line 13 column 3 of AivPumaRequest.xquery:
  XPST0081 XQuery static error near #... fn-bea:inlinedXML(fn:concat#:
    Prefix fn-bea has not been declared
Error on line 44 column 102 of AivPumaRequest.xquery:
  XPST0081 XQuery static error near #... div xdt:dayTimeDuration('P1D'#:
    Prefix xdt has not been declared
Error on line 199 column 3 of AivPumaRequest.xquery:
  XPST0081 XQuery static error near #... fn-bea:inlinedXML(fn:concat#:
    Prefix fn-bea has not been declared
Error on line 282 column 4 of AivPumaRequest.xquery:
  XPST0081 XQuery static error near #... {fn-bea:inlinedXML(fn:concat#:
    Prefix fn-bea has not been declared

net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: Prefix fn-bea has not been declared
```

Is there a way to static include this prefix or what am I missing so my XQuery Engine (SAXON) finds the Prefix?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is that you can declare namespace prefixes either within the query prolog using

```
declare namespace fn-bea = "http://some-appropriate-uri";
```

or in the Saxon API using

```
XQueryCompiler.declareNamespace("fn-bea", "http://some-appropriate-uri")
```

But this won't get you any further unless (a) you know what URI to bind the prefixes to, and (b) you make the functions with these names available to the query processor.

The reference to xdt:dayTimeDuration suggests to me that this query was written when XQuery was still a working draft. If you look at the 2005 working draft, for example

```
https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xquery-20051103/
```

you'll see in section 2 that it uses a built-in prefix

```
xdt = http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes
```

By the time XQuery 1.0 became a recommendation, the `dayTimeDuration` data type had been moved into the standard XML Schema (xs) namespace, so you can probably simply replace "xdt" by "xs" - though you should be aware that the semantics of the language probably changed in minor details as well.

As for `fn-bea:inlinedXML`, the choice of prefix suggests to me that this was probably a built-in vendor extension in the BEA query processor, which was taken over by Oracle. The spec here:

```
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13162_01/odsi/docs10gr3/xquery/extensions.html
```

says:

> fn-bea:inlinedXML Parses textual XML and returns an instance of the
>   XQuery 1.0 Data Model.

Which suggests that the function does something very similar to the XQuery 3.0 function `fn:parse-xml()`, and I suggest you try making that replacement in your query.